# Ruby regular expression for this string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to get the first word in this string: `Basic (11/17/2011 - 12/17/2011)`

So ultimately wanting to get `Basic` out of that.

Other example string: `Premium (11/22/2011 - 12/22/2011)`

The format is always "Single-word followed by parenthesized date range" and I just want the single word.

Comment: Are you searching for that structure within an arbitrary passage of text? The current question phrasing is giving you answers for finding `Basic` within `Basic (11/17/2011 - 12/17/2011)` only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
str = "Premium (11/22/2011 - 12/22/2011)"
str.split.first # => "Premium"
```

The split uses `' '` as default parameter if you don't specify any.
After that, get the first element with `first`

Comment: Where would the date parameter be in this method?

Comment: Like this: `"Premium (11/22/2011 - 12/22/2011)".split.first`

Comment: I think he is expecting variable input. How would you know the "parenthesized date range" is there?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regexp for that, you can just use

```
str.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: This will return the first word whether it appears before a parenthesized date range or not. It also assumed the desired string appears at the beginning of the String.

Comment: What happens when the date parameter is not in the string?

Answer (score 1):

I know you found the answer you are needing but in case anyone stumbles on this in the future, in order to pull the needed value out of a large `String` of unknown length:

```
word_you_need = s.slice(/(\b[a-zA-Z]*\b \(\d+\/\d+\/\d+ - \d+\/\d+\/\d+\))/).split[0]
```

Comment: The `\b.*\b` by itself matches `Basic (11/17/2011 - 12/17/2011)`, even `\b.*?\b` matches `Basic training`.

Comment: Good point. I've changed `\b.*\b` to `\b[a-zA-Z]*\b`. So that should work unless the intended word has a hyphen or any other special character.

Comment: Why not just `/(\S*\s+\(\d+\/\d+\/\d+ - \d+\/\d+\/\d+\))/` then?

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will match the first word with out the trailing space

```
"^\w+ ??"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a regex you can get the first group after using this regex:

```
(\w*) .*
```

Comment: This matches a string containing just a single space.

Comment: The only thing required in your regex is a space, everything else is optional. Therefore a string with a single space matches the space in your regex. Even though '.' will match a space, it won't match it in this case.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying it will not match a string with more than one space. Yes it does indeed match a string consisting of a single space. But the objective of the regex in the context of this question is to extract a part of the input string (using the parenthesis), not to validate it - the last line of the question suggests that we assume it is valid.

Comment: Indeed. You have validated a string containing just a single space and got no data in return. It the goal is to not validate, and get data instead, then `\w+` will get you much further than `(\w*) .*`

Answer (score 0):

"Single-word followed by parenthesized date range"

'word' and 'parenthesized date range' should be better defined
as, by your requirement statement, they should be anchors and/or delimeters.

These raw regex's are just a general guess.

```
\w+(?=\s*\([^)]*\))
```

or

```
\w+(?=\s*\(\s*\d+(?:/\d+)*\s*-\s*\d+(?:/\d+)*\s*\))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you need is:

```
s.split[0]
```

...or...

```
s.split.first
```